# How do I access process.env.VAR in Webpack 5?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I've never used Webpack before and I'm working on a project that's just vanilla JS and HTML. I'm having an issue accessing the values I set in .env. Here's my config.

```js
const path = require("path");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

var webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = () => {

  env = dotenv.config().parsed;
  
  const envKeys = Object.keys(env).reduce((prev, next) => {
    prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(env[next]);
    return prev;
  }, {});
  
  return {
    entry: {
      main: './src/index.js'
    },
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, '../build'),
      filename: '[name].bundle.js'  
    },
    mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
      contentBase: "./src/",
      publicPath: "./src/",
      compress: true,
      port: 9000,
      overlay: true,
      disableHostCheck: true
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    resolve: {
      alias: {
          process: "process/browser"
      }},
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader'
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(png|svg|jpe?g|gif)$/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'file-loader',
              options: {
                name: '[name].[ext]',
                outputPath: 'assets/'
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.html$/,
          use: {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: {
              //attributes: ['img:src', ':data-src'],
              minimize: true
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        process: 'process/browser',
      }),
      new Dotenv(),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html',
        filename: 'index.html'
      }),      
    ]
  }
};
```

As you can see, I'm using dotEnv, definePlugin, and even the dotEnv-webpack plugin. Unfortunately, none of these solutions seem to allow me to access process.env.originURL.

```html
originURL=https://localhost:3000
```

I'm not importing or requiring anything in my javascript file, index.js. I'm assuming this should work, but the console tells me that process is undefined.

```html
console.log(process.env.originURL);
```

How can I access process.env.originURL in my index.js?

Comment: It's working for me, you could show the `package.json` or the `devDependencies`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. Maybe you could try this version:

```js
 new Dotenv({ systemvars: true })
```

If it still doesn't work, please show your package.json, as well as you .env file (randomize the values of course). Is .env at the root of you app?